# RxJS Observable: retry using count and then using notifier

Tags: rxjs, observable, retrywhen

Firstly, I'd like to retry using a simple count:

- Retry the source observable `n` times.
- Then, emit the error.

(Preferably, the error may be emitted immediately after each retry, but `retry(count)` does not seem to do this.)

If I understand correctly, this is the behaviour of `retry(count)`:

```
{
  new Rx.Observable(observer => {
    console.log("subscribe");
    observer.error("ERROR");
  })
    .retry(3)
    .subscribe({
      error: console.log
    });
}
// subscribe
// subscribe
// subscribe
// subscribe
// ERROR
```

Then, I would like to allow the user to retry manually. When a retry notifier observable (`retry$`) emits, retry the observable again, emitting the error each time afterwards.

I tried to use `retryWhen` for this, however whilst the retries do occur, the error is never emitted.

I want to retry but also emit any errors, so that I can display them in the user interface whilst the retry is running.

```
{
  const retrySubject = new Rx.Subject();
  const retry$ = retrySubject.asObservable();
  new Rx.Observable(observer => {
    console.log("subscribe");
    observer.error("ERROR");
  })
    .retryWhen(() => retry$)
    .subscribe({
      error: console.log
    });
  retrySubject.next();
}
// subscribe
// subscribe
```

Furthermore, I'm not sure how to combine this with `retry(count)`. If I chain the retry operators, the would trigger each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`retryWhen` provides a stream of errors - you can peek the stream and ignore it after 3 emissions and then only retry when triggered by user.

```
const retrySubject = new Rx.Subject();
const retry$ = retrySubject.asObservable();
new Rx.Observable(observer => {
  console.log("subscribe");
  observer.error("ERROR");
})
  .retryWhen(errors => Rx.Observable.merge(
    errors
      .do(error => console.log(error)) // log error
      .filter((error, index) => index < 3), // take only first 3 and ignore the rest
    retry$ // also retry with user request
  ))
  .subscribe();

retrySubject.next();
```

You could use `take(3)` instead of `filter` but that would stop the `errors` stream so logging of errors would also stop. `filter` operator will keep it 'running'.

Comment: I want the observable to emit errors as part of the stream, rather than logging as a separate side effect.

Comment: That's not possible, when observable emits error no more elements are emitted, it acts as if the observable is completed but with an error.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I didn't realise that. As what I'm asking for is technically impossible, I'll mark your answer as correct.